# Basic Auth and HttpContext

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, authentication, authorization

I would like to allow HTTP Basic Authentication in ASP MVC and I have noticed that if I try to authenticate with basic auth, the `HttpContext` object's `User` property is null.

Is the way to go forward to create an `IPrincipal` myself by doing *everything* myself or are there ways for the framework to do the auth parsing for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes some work but luckily someone beat you to it and published his code at http://chodounsky.net/2012/05/02/basic-authorization-attribute-in-asp-net-mvc/.

You just need to use his [BasicAuthorize] attribute on your methods, like so:

```
[BasicAuthorize]
public ActionResult SomeControllerMethod()
{
    ... 
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: heh, I would have figured the framework would be able to parse auth headers. Rolling my own is fine though, just a little unexpected. (I tend to find that if I'm reimplementing basic infrastructure in a well established framework, my entire approach is 'doing it wrong', and it's just something you shouldn't be doing in the first place)